# How to pause video on video.js without controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm using video.js. Here's how I have implemented it.

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" loop preload="auto" width="530" height="530" poster="<?php echo $iurl; ?>" autoplay>
<source src="<?php echo $vurl; ?>" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

As you have noticed, the controls are disabled. But I would like to pause this video when it's clicked. Can someone tell me how I can do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the documentation here (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md), the following javascript should work:

**HTML**

```
<video id="example_video_1" onclick="togglePause()" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" loop preload="auto" width="530" height="530" poster="<?php echo $iurl; ?>" autoplay>
<source src="<?php echo $vurl; ?>" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myPlayer = videojs("example_video_1");
togglePause = function(){
  if (myPlayer.paused()) {
    myPlayer.play();
  }
  else {
    myPlayer.pause();
  }
}
```

After being paused, I assumed the video should resume playing? jsFiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fR2Xs/

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented it in the header but it won't work. Here's the source. vinejar.com

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fR2Xs/

After calling the videojs.play() method, the video controls are re-added to the player. I added a CSS override to keep it hidden for the time being.

Comment: `myPlayer.paused()` should be `myPlayer.paused` as it's a property

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is by enabling the controls and setting their display value to none. This way you can pause the video and controls are not visible.

```
.vjs-control-bar, .vjs-big-play-button {
   display: none !important;
}
```